# Cannot use Chinese input language in PowerPoint

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint, language, input, chinese

When I use PowerPoint, I cannot input Chinese text....it just does not do anything.
It works fine in all other Windows programs, like Word, Excel, etc...but not ppt.

Someone said to go to Language setting, details, advanced, and "turn off advanced text services".
This doesn't help...it warns that the language bar will disappear and thus not recommended for Asian font users...
then I am stuck with English input...instead of multi-languages.

There must be a setting which can fix this so that someone can input Chinese in PowerPoint without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create ChinesePowerPoint2007.reg:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\TIP\{5621CC0F-3ABF-428b-BDF0-D8544FD3ED75}\LanguageProfile\0x00000804\{F3BA9077-6C7E-11D4-97FA-0080C882687E}]

"Enable"=dword:00000001
```

Merge to registry, restart PC, test).

Answer (score 0):

I've got an article that explains what you need to do on a PowerPoint FAQ site that I maintain:

Using Japanese, Chinese, Korean (CJK) languages in PowerPoint
[http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00910_Using_Japanese-_Chinese-*Korean*-CJK-_languages_in_PowerPoint.htm](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00910_Using_Japanese-_Chinese-_Korean_-CJK-_languages_in_PowerPoint.htm)

I use this for Japanese fairly regularly; it should work the same for Chinese.